# Angular get multiple value on click

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have such drop-down which is contain `input, and 2 dropdowns` I want to know how can I get this 3 values when I click search button?

#### Screenshot

[image: one]

#### Code

`HTML`

```
<nz-dropdown-menu #menu="nzDropdownMenu">
    <div class="card search-box p-2">
      <div class="mb-2">
        <label for="">Search By {{ column.name }}</label> <br>
        <input nz-input placeholder="Type here..." />
      </div>

      <div class="mb-2">
        <label for="sort">Sort Order</label> <br>
        <nz-select ngModel="none" class="text-left mr-2" style="width:100%;">
            <nz-option nzValue="none" nzLabel="None"></nz-option>
            <nz-option nzValue="asc" nzLabel="Ascending"></nz-option>
            <nz-option nzValue="desc" nzLabel="Descending"></nz-option>
        </nz-select>
      </div>

      <div class="mb-2">
        <label for="op">Filter Column</label> <br>
        <nz-select ngModel="contains" class="text-left mr-2" style="width:100%;">
            <nz-option nzValue="contains" nzLabel="Contains"></nz-option>
            <nz-option nzValue="like" nzLabel="Like"></nz-option>
        </nz-select>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning w-100 mt-2" (click)="search()"><i class="fe fe-search"></i> Search</button>
    </div>
</nz-dropdown-menu>
```

`Component`

```
search(): void {
   // get values here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ReactiveForms`. you can get form value as you needed

**GET FORM DATA USING** `REACTIVEFORMMODULE` :-

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule ,ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
declarations: [],
imports: [ FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule]});

export class AppModule { }
```

**COMPONENT.TS**

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup,FormControl,Validators,FormArray} from '@angular/forms';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
.
.
.
public formName: FormGroup;
constructor(private formsModule: FormsModule) {
 this.formName =  this.formBuilder.group({
   firstName:  [null, Validators.required],
   lastName:  [null, Validators.required],
 })
} 

 onSubmit() {
   console.log(this.formName.value);
 }
```

**COMPONENT.HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="formName" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
   <div>
     <input type="number" formControlName="firstName">
   </div>
   <div>
     <input type="number" formControlName="lastName">
   </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

**OUTPUT in CONSOLE**

```
{firstName : ... , lastName : ...}
```

Hope it will userFull for all !

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use form controls provided by Angular.
like this
----------


 <nz-dropdown-menu #menu="nzDropdownMenu">
    <div class="card search-box p-2">
      <div class="mb-2">
        <label for="">Search By {{ column.name }}</label> <br>
        <input nz-input placeholder="Type here..." formControl="searchControl"/>
      </div>

      <div class="mb-2">
        <label for="sort">Sort Order</label> <br>
        <nz-select ngModel="none" class="text-left mr-2" style="width:100%;" formControl="orderControl">
            <nz-option nzValue="none" nzLabel="None"></nz-option>
            <nz-option nzValue="asc" nzLabel="Ascending"></nz-option>
            <nz-option nzValue="desc" nzLabel="Descending"></nz-option>
        </nz-select>
      </div>

      <div class="mb-2">
        <label for="op">Filter Column</label> <br>
        <nz-select ngModel="contains" class="text-left mr-2" style="width:100%;" formControl="filterControl">
            <nz-option nzValue="contains" nzLabel="Contains"></nz-option>
            <nz-option nzValue="like" nzLabel="Like"></nz-option>
        </nz-select>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning w-100 mt-2" (click)="search()"><i class="fe fe-search"></i> Search</button>
    </div>
</nz-dropdown-menu>
```

---

Your component.ts would look like.

---

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
.
.
.
constructor() {} 
searchControl: FormControl = new FormControl();
filterControl: FormControl = new FormControl();
orderControl: FormControl = new FormControl();

 search() {
    console.log(searchControl.value);
 }
```

---

Or you can use ngModel or form groups...etc

---